# Polymer - Preventing one instance of attribute updating

Tags: polymer

I'm generating a list using DOM repeat. Each item has a title and a date. The date is a string which is formatted by the back-end like this:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDfqM.png)

I bind the [[item.date]] property to a selector element to change the value, but when I then modify that property the format changes to the default Javascript format like this:
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKkxH.png)

Is there any way I can prevent that specific label from updating?

Some code for explanation:

The label:

```
<div>
    <b>Datum: </b>[[item.startdatum]]
</div>
```

The label in question is the [[item.startdatum]]

I'm then editing it in this cell:

```
<td>
   Starttijd:
   <paper-datetime-picker-item date="{{item.startdatum}}" label="Start"locale="nl"></paper-datetime-picker-item>
   <paper-input value="{{item.startdatum}}" hidden name="start"></paper-input>
</td>
```

So what I want is that the first label [[item.startdatum]]  doesn't change when I update it with the date-picker.

Comment: Some code would help...

Comment: @Nicolas Added the code in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format in the `paper-datetime-picker-item`.

```
<paper-datetime-picker-item
  date="{{item.startdatum}}"
  label="Start"
  locale="nl"
  date-format="YYYY-MM-DD kk:mm"
  ></paper-datetime-picker-item>
```

Date format uses the **momentjs** display format. [1]

Also you probably do not need the `paper-input`.

[1] - https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I couldn't find out which property I needed to set for it to be send with the form. So I opted for the quick and dirty way. Does setting the label make it work?

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. It only formats the date field. So now I have the time in both the date and separate in the time field.